# Запуск подгруппы контейнеров

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Можно ли запустить часть контейнеров по метке `docker-compose up --filter "label=my-label"`? Или сделать аналогичным образом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попросту перечислить список сервисов в команде:

`docker-compose up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]`

Никакой ценности в фильтрации сервисов в docker-compose файле по меткам нет, т.к. docker-compose файл статичен.

Если очень хочется - можно накостылить желаемое через cat, jq и bash.

Comment: Да, я сделал makefile. Каждый раз писать 10 контейнеров -- это оверхед )=